# ReSharper formatting of complex object literals

Tags: formatting, resharper, object-literal

When I have complex object literals, ReSharper insists on formatting them with a very liberal use of newlines. For instance, the example below is a formatted example from my code; note how even angle brackets and parenthesis are placed on lines of their own.

```
var myResultItem = new ResultItem
 {
   Investigation =
       new List<Investigation>
       {
           new Investigation
           {
              Id
                =
                  new List
                  <
                  CV
                  >
                    {
                        MyEnum
                          .MyValue
                          .AsCV
                           (
                           )
                     }
                  }
             },
             Item =
                 new TextResult
                     {
                      TextResultValue =
                                 "Some text"                                 
                     }
             };
```

I have tried various R# options, but I have been unable to find what setting it is that triggers this behavior.

For less complex literals, as well as most other code, the formatting looks good.

I'm using ReSharper 8.2 in VS 2013.

Comment: Try unchecking 'ReSharper | Options | Code Editing | C# | Formatting Style | Other | Align Multiline Constructs | Array, object and collection initializer'. Also try increasing a value of 'ReSharper | Options | Code Editing | C# | Formatting Style | Line Breaks and Wrapping | Line Wrapping | Right margin'.

Comment: @Alexander Yes, thank you, that did the trick! Write your comment as an answer, and I will Accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try unchecking `ReSharper | Options | Code Editing | C# | Formatting Style | Other | Align Multiline Constructs | Array, object and collection initializer`. Also try increasing a value of `ReSharper | Options | Code Editing | C# | Formatting Style | Line Breaks and Wrapping | Line Wrapping | Right margin`.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is here: Resharper -> Options -> Code Editing -> C# -> Formatting Style -> Blank Lines

You can modify what triggers a new line.

Comment: No, sorry, that does not seem to help.